# animating one image tag with changing src attribute using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have an application in which the one division contains a image that need to change in every three second. But the problem is that I also need to add some animations to that changing event. I have tried few things but those are not looking very pleasing. Is there any way I can use animate() on this? My code which just changes the images is as follows:

```
var arrayOfImages //asssume that this array have 10 images   
  var i = 0;  
  setInterval(function(){
  $('.imageBox').attr('src', arrayImg[i]); 
  i++; 
  if(i == 10) i=0; 
  }, 3000);
```

Other then this I have tried fadeIn and fadeOut too, but this is also looking very naive.

```
var i = 0;
    setInterval(function(){
        $('.imageBox').fadeOut(500, function() {
            $('.imageBox').attr("src",arrayImg[++i]);
            $('.imageBox').fadeIn(500);
        });
      if(i == 10) i=0; 
      }, 3000);
```

Please any help on this is appreciable. Thank you in advance 
this is link for fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/apf5X/8/

Comment: Please provide a fiddle

Comment: Have a look at [Animate.css](https://daneden.me/animate/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [jQuery Cycle 2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/)?

It's a really powerful plugin with lots of animations. Not only for images but for any html tag!

Comment: yeah its good i tried that today but still having some trouble while dynamically adding slides to it, trying to figure that out now, thankx for suggestion

Comment: but I was looking for something that can be done without any plugin , just a method in javascript that does some magic with animate method of jquery. But this is also fine as it is just one js file

Comment: Yeah, indeed, and it's really lightweight!

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be be easier to use a library.

Here are some suggestions to get you started:

- http://flexslider.woothemes.com/
- http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/

There are many more to choose from. A good keyword to search for would be javascript image slider or jquery image slider.

Comment: these are helpful links @forsvunnet but i dnt want to buy any plugin or something like that, anything that is open to use would be acknowledged but any way its good to know that things are there if needed.